# svg polyline dynamically created in JavaScript not showing on page

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to add a bunch of polylines to a div.  It shows they were successfully created in the elements console, but they are not appearing on the screen.  I have two versions (one tagged out), both produce the same results. 
 I'm testing in Chrome.

```
$(".brktBox").append("<svg id=svgBox width="+bracket.brktBox.width+" height="+bracket.brktBox.height+">")

for (i = 0; i < bracket.lineCoords.length; i++){

    // temp var
    var tv = bracket.lineCoords[i]
    var points = `${tv.pt1x},${tv.pt1y} ${tv.pt2x},${tv.pt2y} ${tv.pt3x},${tv.pt3y} ${tv.pt3x},${tv.pt3y}`;

    //work around from lower version that also doesn't work
    var newLine = document.createElementNS(null,"polyline");
    newLine.setAttributeNS(null, "points", points);
    document.getElementById('svgBox').appendChild(newLine);

    //one version that doesn't work
    // $("#svgBox").append("<polyline class=svgLine id=svg"+i+" />")
    // $("#svg"+i).attr("points", points)
}
```

Also, I understand tv for temp var is terrible.

Comment: You need to pass the SVG namespace string to `createElementNS()`

Comment: Passed the SVG to createElementNS() and changed the element attributes.  Nothing has changed.  SVG is still created with correct width and height and polylines are also still created with correct points.  Polylines still not showing on screen.

Comment: You shouldn't use namespace in the attributes. http://jsfiddle.net/kqn3knve/

Comment: It works.  I don't really understand the solution though.  What is the purpose of the w3 address?

Comment: SVG is not HTML. The elements in an SVG are not HTML elements. Without the distinguishing namespace, the browser just assumes that you want to create your own custom HTML element called `<polyline>`.  That's a perfectly okay thing to do.  The "w3 address" is not a real URL, it just looks like one. It is really just a unique string that means "this is an SVG element".